# Filter within a date range

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `cruise` model which hasMany `trips`. A `trip` stores the start and end date. I'd like to filter `cruises` which start at or later than `earliestStartDate` and which end latests at `latestEndDate`.

**app/models/cruise.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  trips: DS.hasMany('trip', { async: true })
});
```

**app/models/trip.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  starts_on: DS.attr('date'),
  ends_on: DS.attr('date')
});
```

**app/templates/index.hbs**

```
{{date-picker date=earliestStartDate valueFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'}
{{date-picker date=latestEndDate valueFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'}}
```

How can I change `filteredCruises` in this controller to filter the `cruises` which have trips within the given dates?

**app/controllers/index.js**

```
[...]

filteredCruises: function() {
    var earliestStartDate = this.get('earliestStartDate');
    var latestEndDate = this.get('latestEndDate');
    var cruises = this.get('model.cruises');

    return cruises;
}.property('model.cruises','earliestStartDate','latestEndDate'),

[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't touched Ember in a while, and I haven't tested/executed this code, but I *think* this might work for you (and I am sure this can be optimized):

```
[...]

filteredCruises: function() {
    var earliestStartDate = this.get('earliestStartDate');
    var latestEndDate = this.get('latestEndDate');
    var cruises = this.get('model.cruises');

    return cruises.filter(function(cruise) {
        return cruise.get('trips').filter(function(trip) {
            return ((trip.get('starts_on') >= earliestStartDate) && (trip.get('ends_on') <= latestEndDate));
        });
    });

}.property('model.cruises','earliestStartDate','latestEndDate'),

[...]
```